# Can I change my Qt project license?

Tags: gpl, lgpl

I have non-commercial Qt license, but I need a static compilation option because as I know, my program needs many DLL files and I want to have the possibility of running my program on another machine without problems with unfound DLLs.

So, the question is: can I change my non-commercial Qt license in an existing Qt Project to LGPL or GPL? And then will I have static compilation option, without any DLL needs?

And, if so, then what I must do to legally use Qt in that license? I know that I have to give code modification possibility to other people, so can I simply upload my project to Github?

Answer (score 1):

If you want static compilation, but you don't want to release the source to your program, then it looks like you must purchase the commercial license ([https://www.qt.io/licensing-comparison/)](https://www.qt.io/licensing-comparison/) I am not a lawyer, but I imagine Qt probably has some guidelines on if/how you can migrate from Qt free to Qt commercial.

If you wish to stick with the free license and use static linking, then you will have to release the source for both Qt and the program that you have developed. How you deploy your program determines your options for distributing the source code. For example, if you deploy your program via some website, it is probably acceptable to add a hyperlink to the source on the same webpage that you can download the compiled program. If you are delivering the program inside of some embedded device, then you should probably either (1) Show the required [L]GPL notifications (show notification on paper or electronically) and give them the opportunity to request the source via some physical medium in the mail (e.g. USB drive, DVD, CD, etc) or (2) Ship a copy of the source along with the embedded device (e.g. ship a CD containing the required source)